# Please help me type following words in Hindi

Tags: keyboard, keyboard-layout, language-support

I have keyboard 'Indian' selected because I am comfortable with the Hindi Inscript keyboard of Windows. How do I type the various forms of r in the following Hindi words? I do not want to use any other keyboard layout.

[image: word 1]
[image: word 2]

Comment: For reference, the words are कर्ण and कृष्णा .

Comment: Try using my method: run the command `uniname -bce <<< "ज्ञ"`

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried looking at the 'Keyboard Layout Chart' found under the language indicator? You'll find every key and how it's mapped on your keyboard based on the 'Indian' layout.
If you can't find the letter that way, you can always use the Character Map, found on the list of Ubuntu apps.

Comment: thank you very much Felipe. by looking at the Keyboard layout chart I could type both these words.

Comment: No problem. Feel free to mark this as the accepted answer, so other can also benefit from it

Answer (score 1):

I don't speak or read Hindi, but I ran `uniname` on the words, which hopefully gives the method for typing them:

```
$ uniname -bce <<< 'कर्ण'
UTF-32   glyph   name
000915  क      DEVANAGARI LETTER KA
000930  र      DEVANAGARI LETTER RA
00094D  ्      DEVANAGARI SIGN VIRAMA
000923  ण      DEVANAGARI LETTER NNA
$ uniname -bce <<< 'कृष्णा'
UTF-32   glyph   name
000915  क      DEVANAGARI LETTER KA
000943  ृ      DEVANAGARI VOWEL SIGN VOCALIC R
000937  ष      DEVANAGARI LETTER SSA
00094D  ्      DEVANAGARI SIGN VIRAMA
000923  ण      DEVANAGARI LETTER NNA
00093E  ा      DEVANAGARI VOWEL SIGN AA
```

Comment: thank you very much. using keyboard map i could figure out how to type. This keyboard layout is a little different from the one that i use in Windows to type these slight transformations of Devanagari Letter ra.